# schweizerisch, Schweizer oder Schweizerin?

Tags: gender, proper-noun

In meinem Kursbuch habe ich einen Text gelesen und da steht Folgendes: „Eine **Schweizer** Journalistin“.
Warum nicht „eine Schweizerin Journalistin“, wenn das Wort weiblich ist?

Man sagt Schweizerin, nur wenn es als Substantiv benutzt wird? Zum Beispiel, Die Schauspielerin ist Schweizerin.

Und warum nicht „eine schweizerische Journalistin“? Kann Schweizer und schweizerisch austauschbar sein?

Comment: "Schweizer" ist in diesem Kontext ein Adjektiv und dementsprechend gibt es die weibliche Form mit "-in", nicht, die gibt es nur bei Substantiven. Du kannst genauso gut "schweizerisch" benutzen, ist etwas weniger gebräuchlich und wird kleingeschrieben. Hier die entsprechende [Regel beim Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung#D90)

Answer (score -1):

Nur eine Vermutung:
Länder werden normalerweise mit "isch" genannt, also
österreichische, amerikanische, britische, grönländische, ... Journalistin.
Somit wäre "schweizerische Journalistin" dem internationalen Muster folgend.
Die "Schweizer Journalistin" wäre sicherlich (auch) dann richtig, wenn sie eine weltberühmte Sonderstellung hätte, wie zum Beispiel das "Schweizer Messer" oder "Schweizer Schokolade" oder das "Schweizer Bankgeheimnis".
Man sagt auch "Wiener Schnitzel" und nicht "wienerisches Schnitzel".
Aber auch "Wiener Journalist" und nicht "wienerischer Journalist", ausser man will hier auf seine Berichterstattung in bestem Wiener Dialekt hinweisen.
Aber da sind wir jetzt bei den Städten, nicht Ländern!
Da die Schweiz so klein ist, kommt da vermutlich der Stadtcharakter durch - "Schweizer Alpenvieh" eben, nicht "Ö/österreichisches Rind" (beachte Groß/Kleinschreibung). Geht es darum, ob das Rind in der Schweiz oder in Österreich grast, wird man sagen "österreichische/schweizer(ische) Kuh". Ginge es aber um eine berühmte Rinderrasse, so würden die Experten über das "Österreichische Rind" diskutieren, über das "Schweizer Rind" natürlich auch.
Ähnlich vielleicht die "Liechtensteiner Journalistin", bei der aus Luxemburg geht vermutlich beides - "luxemburgische" und "Luxemburger Journalistin".
Fazit: Bei Stadtstaaten und Kleinstaaten gehen wohl beide Möglichkeiten.
Ich denke aber es gibt Gelehrte (z.B. Telemax), die das noch genauer sagen können.
Falsch ist aber sicherlich die "Schweizerin Journalistin", denn das klingt "böhmisch" für den Nativ-Deutschsprachigen.

Comment: Gleiches gilt übrigens für die _Wiener Journalistin_. Das scheint ja ein zentraler Zweifel des Fragestellers zu sein.

Comment: Die Abwertung kam nicht von mir. Es sei aber gesagt, dass _Vermutungen_ hier unerwünscht sind. Diese Seite ist als Referenz für zukünftige Recherchen gedacht, und sollte nur belegbare Fakten als Antworten enthalten.